# Help with a query - TSQL

Tags: t-sql

I am really struggling with the issue below and need some help...I have found few responses but not leading me the right way...

### Table1

```
 sub-id  ref-id    Name
    1       1         Project 1
    2       1         Project 2  
    3       2         Project 3
    4       2         Project 4-
```

### Table2

```
 sub-id  ref-id    log_stamp      Recepient      log_type
    ----------------------------------------------------
    1     1       06/06/2011     person A       1
    1     1       06/14/2011     person B       2
    1     1       06/16/2011     person C       2
    1     1       06/17/2011     person D       3
    2     1       06/18/2011     person E       2
    2     1       06/19/2011     person F       2

    3     2       06/20/2011     person G       1
    4     2       06/23/2011     person H       3
```

### Result

```
Name        ref-id    start_date    Recepient     latest_comment Recepient completion_date  Receipient
Project1    1         06/06/2011    person A      06/19/2011     person F      06/17/2011   person D
Project3    2         06/20/2011    person G      NULL           NULL          06/23/2011   person H
```

> log_type of 1 stands for start_date
>   log_type of 2 stands for
>   latest_comment log_type of 3 stands
>   for completion_date we need to
>   max_date in the date column to be
>   displayed for each log_type. The Name
>   of the project is just the name of the
>   top-most name in the same group of
>   ref-id have tried this for now

Comment: What query did you use? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am just trying diplay a summary view for the items in Table 2..

Comment: Was the performance better this time ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599771/question-with-a-query/6608108#6608108 I am unable to test it myself until monday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server 2005+:

```
WITH cteMaxDates AS (
    SELECT sub_id, ref_id, log_type, MAX(log_stamp) AS MaxDate
        FROM Table2
        GROUP BY sub_id, ref_id, log_type
),
cteRecipient AS (
    SELECT md.sub_id, md.ref_id, md.log_type, md.MaxDate, t2.Recipient
        FROM cteMaxDates md
            INNER JOIN Table2 t2
                ON md.sub_id = t2.sub_id 
                    AND md.ref_id = t2.ref_id
                    AND md.log_type = t2.log_type
                    AND md.MaxDate = t2.log_stamp
)
SELECT t1.Name, t1.ref_id, 
       start.MaxDate AS start_date,
       start.Recipient AS start_recipient,
       comment.MaxDate AS latest_comment,
       comment.Recipient AS comment_recipient,
       complete.MaxDate AS completion_date,
       complete.Recipient AS completion_recipient
    FROM Table1 t1
        LEFT JOIN cteRecipient start
            ON t1.sub_id = start.sub_id
                AND t1.ref_id = start.ref_id
                AND start.log_type = 1
        LEFT JOIN cteRecipient comment
            ON t1.sub_id = comment.sub_id
                AND t1.ref_id = comment.ref_id
                AND comment.log_type = 2
        LEFT JOIN cteRecipient complete
            ON t1.sub_id = complete.sub_id
                AND t1.ref_id = complete.ref_id
                AND complete.log_type = 3
```

Comment: +1 from me, last time that question was up, it wasnt answered for ages. I am wondering why you are not using outer join like i did (check my other comment for link)

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: You're right. `LEFT JOIN` is probably more appropriate here based on the sample data given. I'll update.

Comment: Can you compare performance on our scripts ? I dont have access to a database until monday.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: I'd leave the benchmarking as an exercise for the OP as he probably has access to better sample data than we could generate.